# How to detect a touch or click on <body>?

Tags: jquery

I have a script to detect mouse clicks, but it does not seem to get triggered on mobile touches. How can I make it trigger when someone touches the anything inside the  tag on mobile?

```
$(window).click(function() {

    closeSideBar();

});

$('mySidenav').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Targeting window will never work. Use some selector, best in my opinion would bbe $('body').on('click')...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$("body").on("click", function() {
    closeSideBar();
});
```